# Does DbDataAdapter.Fill append rows to the table if called multiple times?

Tags: .net, vb.net

I have inherited some rather messy, undocumented code and I'm unsure of this method's behavior:

```
pclsAuditLog = New Data.clsAuditLog()
pclsAuditLog.mfpGetAuditLog(pDS)

pclsPROcAuditLog = New PROcData.clsAuditLog()
pclsPROcAuditLog.mfpGetAuditLog(pDS)
```

Both `Data.clsAuditLog.mfpGetAuditLog(ByRef ds As DataSet)` and `PROcData.clsAuditLog.mfpGetAuditLog(ByRef ds As DataSet)` call this method:

```
Public Function mGetDataSet(ByRef objDs As DataSet, ByVal aStrDSName As String)
    Dim pObjDataAdaptor As New SqlClient.SqlDataAdapter

    pObjDataAdaptor.SelectCommand = New SqlCommand(aStrQuery, pCon)
    pObjDataAdaptor.SelectCommand.CommandTimeout = 3600

    pObjDataAdaptor.Fill(aObjDS, aStrDSName)
End Function
```

I wish I had answers as to why any of this code is written this way, but it's what I was given and I'm trying to make sense of it all.

Anyways, my question is, what happens when an `SqlDataAdapter` calls the `Fill` method using a reference to the same `DataSet` object?

[MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/y4b211hz(v=vs.110).aspx) discusses a lot of behavior as far as what happens with case-sensitivty concerns, different table names and things of that manner however I cannot seem to find an answer as to whether or not rows get appended or overwritten, when there is an existing Table with the same name. Specifically,

> If Fill is called and the DataSet contains only one DataTable whose name differs only by case, that DataTable is updated. In this scenario, the comparison is case insensitive. The following C# code illustrates this behavior.

What does "updated" mean? Unfortunately, I am unable to test specifically what happens at this time. Just hoping someone would know off the top of their head.

Comment: This statement: "I have inherited some rather messy, undocumented code " is redundant; you could have just said, "I have inherited some code"

Comment: Sql Server Express is free to download, I suggest you install it on your dev PC so you can run experiments. You may even be able to restore a backup of the live database to your dev PC. P.S. the "with tools" version is the one you'll want

Comment: Thanks, @SSS but I have everything all configured at work. I just wasn't at the office when I posted this

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From [msdn](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zxkb3c3d%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

> When using subsequent Fill calls to refresh the contents of the
>   DataSet, two conditions must be met:
>
> ```
> The SQL statement should match the one initially used to populate the DataSet.
>
> The Key column information must be present.
> ```
>
> **If primary key information is present, any duplicate rows are
>   reconciled and only appear once in the DataTable that corresponds to
>   the DataSet.** Primary key information may be set either through
>   FillSchema, by specifying the PrimaryKey property of the DataTable, or
>   by setting the MissingSchemaAction property to AddWithKey

The emphasis is mine. So it seems like "updated" means appended, unless that would cause a primary key violation.

Comment: Thanks, I think you're right. I'll double check and mark this correct tomorrow.

Comment: Just checking back in. You are in fact correct, the rows returned from the second call are appended to the correct `DataTable` within the `DataSet`. Thanks! I did read this snippet yesterday but I didn't really understand it.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you should inspect SqlDataAdapter reference code at [Microsoft Reference Source](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Data/System/Data/SqlClient/SqlDataAdapter.cs,ef2c0646f1d3248d)